# How to Import .dae file to scene and simply change its position

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

dae file that I exported from blender. (Blender is a software used to make 3D object and animations). The problem is that when I add the .dae file into the scene in scene kit. The Box will appear but thats it. Even with the code below I still can't manipulate the Box to even do things as simple as setting its position or scaling it up or down. Its like it reject all things except the fact that it can be put in the scene. So I decided to make a test object to manipulate. I called it simply "sphere1" and I am able to manipulate it in all aspects by code. But the .dae file won't do anything at all.

Code:

This is the test circle everythings good here the sphere has a physics body and I can scale it and change its position. It even falls do to gravity I set to -9.8

```
    var sphere1: SCNNode!
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 4.5)
    let sphereMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    let collisionCapsuleRadius = CGFloat(3.0)
    let collisionCapsuleHeight = CGFloat(3.0)
    sphereMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor.greenColor()
    sphereGeometry.materials = [sphereMaterial]
    sphere1 = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphere1.position = SCNVector3(x: 20.0, y: 10.0, z: 0.05)
    sphere1.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    sphere1.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 0

    //----Giveing it a physics---------
    sphere1.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius, height: collisionCapsuleHeight), options:nil))
    sphere1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    sphere1.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    sphere1.physicsBody?.restitution = 1 //bounceness of the object
    sphere1.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // rotationess
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere1)
```

This is the "box" and I can't not even change its position are simple scale it at all.

```
    let TestBox = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/TestCube.dae")
    let Box: SCNNode = TestBox!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Cube", recursively: true)!
    Box.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -30.0, z: 0.0)
    Box.scale = SCNVector3Make(100, 100, 100)
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(Box)
```

Just to be share its a problem with all .dae file imported and not just that one I imported early. I imported another .dae/.scn file to see if I can manipulate it and still no luck.

```
     let GuyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/FoxMan2.scn")
    let Guy: SCNNode = GuyScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Guy", recursively: true)!
    let collisionCapsuleRadius2 = CGFloat(0.1)
    let collisionCapsuleHeight2 = CGFloat(0.1)
    Guy.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 30.0, z: 0.0)
    Guy.scale = SCNVector3Make(100, 100, 100)
    Guy.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, 1 )
    //----Giveing it a physics---------
    Guy.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape:SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNCapsule(capRadius: collisionCapsuleRadius2, height: collisionCapsuleHeight2), options:nil))
    Guy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    Guy.physicsBody?.friction = 0 //
    Guy.physicsBody?.restitution = 1 //bounceness of the object
    Guy.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 1 // rotationess
    Guy.physicsBody?.mass = 1
    Guy.physicsBody?.rollingFriction = 0

    GuyScene!.rootNode.addChildNode(Guy)
    scnView.scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(Guy)
```

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. Have you tried inspecting the dae file in the Xcode editor window? Check that the node tree is what you're expecting and that Cube is indeed the node you want (or a parent).

Comment: I got it to work it actually has something to do with Blender the animation software I an using apparently you have to import the .dae scene separately from the amateur attached to it